# InitMap() google map api error in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps in my React project. It works fine but in the console, I get the error:

```
Uncaught Ob {message: "initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError"
```

I tried a few solutions but nothing seems to work. My code current code:

```
</head>

  <script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap">
  </script>

  <script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js">
  </script>

  <body>
```

(it is between head and body). And I use the map in on of js files like this:

```
function initMap(form, type, id, legendType) {
    ...

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
    return hashMap;
}
```

Do I need to call somewhere simple `initMap()` without any parameters?

Comment: Is `initMap` a function available in the global scope?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I needed to create initMap() function and put the script with it before the script with google maps. Final code:

```
<script>
    initMap = function(){}
  </script>

  <script
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap">
  </script>
```